# Python: Putting two diffrent entries from one array together

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, merge

I got stucked with something really easy (probably):

I have one list, where list entry [0] should be merged with list entry [1] and [2] with [3] and so on.

At the end, after the pairs got merged, I would like to save the outcome in a new list.
The for loops I created so far, never worked, so is there maybe someone who could help me?

## Thank you very much!

Like that:

```
list1 = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"]
list2 = []

# The Output for list2 should be like: ["A1A2", "B1B2", "C1C2"]
```

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stackoverflow! Can you please write code that attempts a partial solution even if it doesn't fully work. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Take a look at [range](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) function, and [join](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join) method.

Comment: `list2 = [x+y for x,y in zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2])]` For explanation have a look by yourself at the docs and search for list slices, zip and list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `range` function to get even indexes.

```
list2 = []

for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
    value = list1[i] + list1[i + 1]
    list2.append(value)
```

Comment: A bit cleaner with a list comprehension: `list2 = [list1[i]+list1[i+1] for i in range(0,len(list1),2)]`

Comment: Thank you so much Oleksandr, you helped me a lot! It works now :)
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension solution -

```
[list1[i]+list1[i+1] for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)]
```

And a `join` is not far if you have above list comprehension -

```
["".join(x[i: i+2]) for i in range(0, len(x), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Solution**
list1 = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2","D1"]
list2 = []
index_1 = 1

for item in list1:
#    print(item)
    if index_1 % 2:
        list2.append(item)
    else:
        list2[len(list2) - 1] = list2[len(list2) - 1] + item
    index_1 = index_1 + 1


 print(list2)
```